# How to access sqlite data in Android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)

I'm writing Android application with c# and I Use sqlite to store My Data.
I want to fetch the data from the database and display into textview but returns null.

```
  protected void GetCursorView(string username, string sValue)
    {
        Android.Database.ICursor icTemp = dt.GetRecordCursor(username, sValue);
        if (icTemp != null)
        {
            icTemp.MoveToFirst();
            name.Text = icTemp.GetString(1);//name is TextView
            post.Text = icTemp.GetString(3);
        }
        else
        {
            tresult.Text = dt.Message;
        }
    }
```

How to display data from sqlite on Textview?